# How to disable days untill today in datepicker?

Tags: angular, datepicker

I'm using the `datepicker` from here  https://github.com/kekeh/mydatepicker/blob/master/README.md and i need to disable the dates until today so i need get the current day month and year and pass it myDatePickerOptions i used new Date() function to get the date in which I'm getting like this (Thu Apr 06 2017 15:55:09 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) so can't use it `myDatepickerOptions` How can get the day month and year? I have tried the following code.

```
import { Component, OnInit,ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { HeaderComponent } from  '../header/header.component';
import {IMyOptions, IMyDateModel,IMyDate} from 'mydatepicker';
import { TimepickerConfig } from 'ng2-bootstrap/timepicker';
import { FormGroup,FormControl,Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-createsession',
  templateUrl: './createsession.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./createsession.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class CreatesessionComponent implements OnInit {

  eventform : FormGroup ;

  public mytime: Date = new Date();

  private myDatePickerOptions: IMyOptions = {
        //  need use the current day,month and year 

        disableUntil: {year: 2016, month: 8, day: 10},
        dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yyyy'
    };
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.mytime);

    });

  }
  onDateChanged(event: IMyDateModel) {
        // event properties are: event.date, event.jsdate, event.formatted and event.epoc
    }   




onSubmit(){
  console.log(this.eventform.value);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract the date, year and month from the current date and set it to the disableUntil property.

```
public mytime: Date = new Date();

currentYear: any = this.mytime.getUTCFullYear();
currentDate: any = this.mytime.getUTCDate();
currentMonth: any = this.mytime.getUTCMonth() + 1; //months from 1-12

private myDatePickerOptions: IMyOptions = {
    //  need use the current day,month and year 

    disableUntil: {year: this.currentYear, month: this.currentMonth, day: this.currentDate},
    dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yyyy'
};
```

Comment: where should i set the currentyear,currentdate and month in the ngOnInit() method ??

Comment: you can place it just below the mytime. Please find my updated answer.